# Android WebView heigh include the heigh of “navigation bar”？

Tags: android, html

the target URL：http://www.bong.cn/dafeiji/

the layout file：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/header"/>
    <WebView
            android:id="@+id/Webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

on nexus5 Android5.1：what's wrong?
[image]
[image]

Comment: set FULLSCREEN is working: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Answer (score 0):

In your styles add android:windowActionBarOverlay to your theme and set it to false. That should do the trick.

Comment: That does both the action bar and the bottom bar. Did you try putting it in?